# Rails 4 Checklist form + validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a model called Directive that belongs to the User model, the Directive model has 5 fields (strings). I created a form_for and each field have 5 checkboxes, each checkbox has a number value.

So far, so good. The problem is when I try to submit the form. The checkboxes I checked don't persist on error and they're not being submited. My params are blank.

It work fine with radio buttons though.

Example of my form:

```
<%= form_for(@directive, url: dashboard_directives_path(:type => params[:type]), html: {method: "post", class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.check_box :place, "1" %>
  <%= f.check_box :place, "2" %>
  <%= f.check_box :place, "3" %>
  ...
  <%= f.check_box :field2, "1" %>
  ...

<% end %>
```

This is my controller action:

```
def new
  @directive = current_member.directives.new
end

def create
  @directive = current_member.directives.new(directive_params)
  if @directive.save
    redirect_to dashboard_path, :success => "Directive created with success!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

The params in my controller:

```
private

def directive_params
  if params[:directive].present?
    params.require(:directive).permit(:place, :field2, :field3, :field4, :field5)
  else
    params.fetch(:directive, {})
  end
end
```

And the model:

```
class Directive < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :members, :class_name => 'Member', :foreign_key => 'member_id'
  validates :place, :field2, :field3, :field4, :field5, presence: true
end
```

Comment: As this will need quite a bit of debugging, let's discuss this on chat chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `directive_params` as below:

**NOTE**: Pass 'place` as an array also mandatorily as the last argument.

```
def directive_params 
  if params[:directive].present? 
    params.require(:directive).permit( :field2, :field3, :field4, :field5, :place => []) 
  else 
    params.fetch(:directive, {}) 
  end 
end
```

Pass 'place' as an array.

And in your model `Directive` serialize it by adding `serialize :place`.

---

Also I had to change my checkboxes to look like this:

```
<%= f.check_box :place, {:multiple => true}, "1", nil %>
```